# Access gameobjects properties from collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, transform, gameobject

So I have a missile. When it hits its target the **missile** explodes.
The explosion has a radius, inside which may be many enemies.
The enemies have a "scripted/public variable" explosionPrefab.
I find all the enemies using colliders in MissileMove class:

```
Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere( transform.position, explosionRadius );
    foreach (Collider coli in colliders)
        if (coli.tag == "Enemy")
            Damage( coli.gameObject);
```

How do I access the enemies' explosionPrefabs via their transforms ?

EDIT - after reading...

My problem was that the explosionPrefab (enemyMove class) was defined as a Transform. It is now a GameObject. And it works : )

However, instantiating the explosion throws an "invalidCastException" and exits the function. The explosion runs (!), but the rest of the function is skipped - the enemy survives!

But if I "attach" the same explosionPrefab to the local script (MissileMove), and use that in stead, it runs normally (no exception thrown) - what's the difference?

```
void Damage( GameObject enemy )
{
    GameObject exp = enemy.GetComponent<EnemyMove>().explosionPrefab;

    Debug.Log("Start EnemyExplosion");

    // Below throws exception, runs, then quits function
    GameObject explosion = Instantiate( exp, enemy.transform.position, enemy.transform.rotation);

    // Below runs perfectly
    GameObject explosion = Instantiate( enemyExplosion, enemy.transform.position, enemy.transform.rotation);

    Destroy(explosion, 2f);

    Debug.Log("EnemyExplosion startet");

    Destroy(enemy);
}
```

Exception:

> InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>   (wrapper castclass) System.Object.__castclass_with_cache(object,intptr,intptr)
>   UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate[T] (T original, UnityEngine.Vector3 position, UnityEngine.Quaternion rotation) (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Scripting/UnityEngineObject.bindings.cs:276)
>   BulletMove.Damage (UnityEngine.GameObject enemy) (at Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:60)
>   BulletMove.HitTarget () (at Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:49)
>   BulletMove.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/BulletMove.cs:26)

Comment: Not quite clear what you're asking ... you want `coli.gameObject` ? or `coli.transform.gameObject` (basically the same but the first is one API call less). Or use `coli.GetComponent<YourClass>().explosionPrefab`

Comment: Ahh, so that's what getComponent is for : ) - I'll try...

Comment: maybe start here https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/getcomponent

Comment: What is the difference between `enemyExplosion` and `exp`? Is the exception throw in this line? Or do they maybe have some components attached where it happens? Could you post the complete exception output?

Comment: No difference - it's the same prefab

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GetComponentInChildren` or `GetComponent` in your enemies when using the `Physics.OverlapSphere` and then get from that class the respective explosion.